# Send parameter from Portlet doView to portal_normal.vm

Tags: liferay, liferay-velocity

I'm trying to send a parameter from Portlet `doView` function to `portal_normal.vm`

Is it possible? How can I send and receive it?

---

Sorry, but I can't see the way to do through request.

In doView I wrote

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
        httpRequest.setAttribute("hola", "hola");
```

And in the portal normal I tried with:

```
#set ($holas =$request.get('attributes').get('hola'))
#set ($holas2 = $request.getSession().getAttribute("hola"))

$holas
$holas2
```

but Velocity only shows `$holas $holas2`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an overly specific plan to display some information outside of the portlet - but also well outside the portlet spec. Is it possible? Yes. Does it have limitations? Yes.

I didn't try it, but I'd argue that you don't have any guarantee that all render phases of all portlets have been finished before `portal_normal.vm` starts to be evaluated. Technically it's only necessary to have them finished once they are actually about to render. Render is not allowed to change any state - and you're implying that in your case it might do - because on render something else will be displayed.

It might make sense to rather assume that your theme has some DOM element that is available on the page. Then render some javascript that manipulates this DOM element. The dependency on the theme is the same, but you could also fall back to some default rendering in case you can't find the DOM element.

Alternatively, if you insist on your mode of operation. you might try to go through the servlet-session (portlet session won't help) as you have access to the HttpServletRequest from portal_normal.vm. Be warned though: Access to HttpServletRequest is nonstandard and not really portal-thinking